# Explaination of Python code snippet

Tags: python

For a class assignment, I'm analyzing how Amazon's Kindle digital rights management implementation works as well as how to defeat it.  In my research, I came across a set of Python scripts that extract out the book data from the encryption.  It fits my needs for explaining the encryption-cracking part of my paper.

Problem is, I'm not fluent in Python or have any experience other than `print 'Hello World'`.

When working my way through the source code, I came across this snippet

```
def __init__(self, infile):
    # initial sanity check on file
    self.data_file = file(infile, 'rb').read()
    self.mobi_data = ''
    self.header = self.data_file[0:78]

    if self.header[0x3C:0x3C+8] != 'BOOKMOBI' and self.header[0x3C:0x3C+8] != 'TEXtREAd':
        raise DrmException("invalid file format")

    self.magic = self.header[0x3C:0x3C+8]
    self.crypto_type = -1
```

My interpretation of the code goes like this:

1. `self.data_file` is a byte array that is returned by `read()` on the `file(infile, 'rb')` call.
2. `self.header` is the value of the first 79 bytes of the data file

The problem I'm having is just what does `self.header[0x3C:0x3C+8]` mean?

Comment: The length of `[0:78]` is 78, not 79. A slice doesn't include the ending value, so it's `0..77`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, most code I work with has the last value inclusive, not exclusive.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a normal slicing, like `self.data_file[0:78]`, except uses hex literal as the offset. `0x3C` is 60 in base10, so it's the same as `self.header[60:60+8]`.

Answer (score 2):

`self.header[0x3C:0x3C+8]` will get a string of 8 bytes from the `header`, starting at offset 0x3C.